# Rails traverse hash from API XML response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have this hash that I received from an API, using Httparty. The response was an XML but httparty showed it as a hash. But it is soo deep, it gets confusing to get the values.

{"**air_search_result**"=>{"xmlns"=>"http://www.cleartrip.com/air/", "**onward_solutions**"=>{"**solution**"=>[{"index"=>"1", "**pricing_summary**"=>{"base_fare"=>"3350.0", "taxes"=>"7828.55", "total_fare"=>"11178.55"}, "**flights**"=>{"**flight**"=>{"**segments**"=>{"**segment**"=>[{"index"=>"1", "departure_airport"=>"BOM", "arrival_airport"=>"BLR", "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T09:15:00", "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T10:50:00", "flight_number"=>"639", "airline"=>"AI", "operating_airline"=>"AI", "stops"=>"0", "equipment"=>"319", "duration"=>"5700"}, {"index"=>"2", "departure_airport"=>"BLR", "arrival_airport"=>"DEL", "arrival_terminal"=>"3", "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T20:10:00", "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T22:40:00", "flight_number"=>"404", "airline"=>"AI", "operating_airline"=>"AI", "stops"=>"0", "equipment"=>"320", "duration"=>"9000"}]}}}, "**pax_pricing_info_list**"=>{"**pax_pricing_info**"=>{"pax_type"=>"ADT", "**pricing_info_list**"=>{"**pricing_info**"=>{"index"=>"1", "fare_basis_code"=>"SAP30,SAP30", ........

I need to get inside and show airline, departure_airport, etc.

"flights"=>{"flight"=>{"segments"=>{"segment"=>

```
<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].each do|h| %>
<strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - 
<% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"] %>
<%= end %>
```

When I include ["airline"], rails 4 conviniently says **can't convert String into Integer**. But I can get ["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"]
I tried many variations, nested loops but alas, it does not work.

> I am also wondering if there is any gem or method which can directly
>   give the result instead of such deep traversing

EDIT

```
<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].map do|h| %>
  <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - 
  <% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map do |s| %>
    <%= s["airline"] %>
  <% end %><br> <hr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"] is an array, not a hash. If you want to call `['airline']` on it, you need to prepend it with `first`.

Comment: h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"]["first"]["airline"] ??

Comment: how did you conclude it is an array and not a hash? Httparty gives a hash as parsed_response. Right?

Comment: `"segment"=>[{"index"=>"1",` note the square bracket which denotes an array. You need to call `h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].first["airline"]`

Comment: Two things. `First` Now for "departure_airport" will it be like `[0]["departure_airport"]. If you notice, there are two `index` for the `segment`. For second will it be `[1]["departure_airport"]`?. `Second` At some places, there is only one index. How will I know to include only available, coz if say `[1]` it will return error.

Comment: you can use `each` the same way you dealt with an array `@flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56760/discussion-between-arjun-and-broisatse).

Comment: Now I get this error - `The document "Flights not available." does not have a valid root` - for the very first line `@flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"]`

Comment: This is most likely because you got no flight information from API.

Comment: Yes that is what happened. Can you tell me how to put the each in this case. I will get an idea at least. there are more parameters like this.

Comment: You have an example in your own code. :)

Comment: Pls man tell me. I cant wrap my head around `[0] &[1]`. How can I put that in a block. You know what at some point i even tried - `@flight.find_all {|k,v| k.any? { |m| m.downcase == "airline" } }` but rails says it does not know `any?`. how funny?

Comment: I just got my api running again. Prepending `first` or `[0]` is not working. With `first` it still says `can't convert String into Integer` and with `[0]` it says `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Please. The prob is the way I am parsing the array of hashes. Your are teasing me. U know something.

Comment: If you are getting `undefined method for nil` it probably mean that `h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"] ` is nil. You will hit a lot of issues with this approach. Best use nokogiri to parse xml and then search the results with valid xpath (Those are broad topics, google them and try them by yourself before asking more questions)

Answer (score 4):

see the comment from "**BroiSatse**": "h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"] is an array, not a hash."

```
<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].each do|h| %>
  <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - 
  <%= h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"][0]["airline"] %>
<%= end %>
```

or with first

```
<% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].first["airline"] %>
```

or show all "airline"

```
h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map{|s| s["airline"]}
# return: ["AI", "AI"]
```

or show join separator

```
h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map{|s| s["airline"]}.join(', ')
```

or show more data

```
<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].each do|h| %>
  <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - 
  <% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].each do |s| %>
    <%= "#{s['airline']} (#{s['flight_number']})" %>
  <% end %>
<%= end %>
```

You can check in the rails console. Part from API response:

```
h= {"flights"=>
  {"flight"=>
    {"segments"=>
      {"segment"=>
        [{"equipment"=>"319",
          "stops"=>"0",
          "duration"=>"5700",
          "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T09:15:00",
          "index"=>"1",
          "airline"=>"AI",
          "flight_number"=>"639",
          "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T10:50:00",
          "arrival_airport"=>"BLR",
          "departure_airport"=>"BOM",
          "operating_airline"=>"AI"},
         {"equipment"=>"320",
          "stops"=>"0",
          "duration"=>"9000",
          "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T20:10:00",
          "arrival_terminal"=>"3",
          "index"=>"2",
          "airline"=>"AI",
          "flight_number"=>"404",
          "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-06T22:40:00",
          "arrival_airport"=>"DEL",
          "departure_airport"=>"BLR",
          "operating_airline"=>"AI"}]}}},
 "index"=>"1",
 "pricing_summary"=>
  {"taxes"=>"7828.55", "base_fare"=>"3350.0", "total_fare"=>"11178.55"}}


h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].first["airline"] # 'AI'

h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"][0]["airline"] # "AI"

h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map{|s| s["airline"]}.join(', ') # "AI, AI"

h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].each { |s| puts "#{s['airline']} (#{s['flight_number']})" }
# AI (639)
# AI (404)
```

Comment: Alright. Two things. `First` Now for "departure_airport" will it be like `[0]["departure_airport"]. If you notice, there are two `index` for the `segment`. For second will it be `[1]["departure_airport"]`?. `Second` At some places, there is only one index. How will I know to include only available, coz if say `[1]` it will return error.

Comment: Now I get this error - `The document "Flights not available." does not have a valid root` - for the very first line `@flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"]`

Comment: I am also wondering if it is possible that instead of traversing so much, possible to do something like - `@flight.find_all {|k,v| k.any? { |m| m.downcase == "airline" } }` but rails says it does not know `any?`. how funny?

Comment: The show more data eg wont work. I hd tried that variation of loop. it returns `can't convert String into Integer`

Comment: I just got my api running again. Prepending `first` or `[0]` is not working. With `first` it still says `can't convert String into Integer` and with `[0]` it says `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Hallo, can you post full response form your API. My code work with response form your question.

Comment: It is a massive amount of data. I am posting a part of the parsed_response from httparty. - http://jsfiddle.net/PP9N5/

Comment: It is from the beginning. What i posted on the ques was also frm the beginning

Comment: [100] pry(main)> @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].map{ |h| h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map{|s| s["airline"]}.join(', ') }
=> ["AI, AI"]

Comment: `<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].map do|h| %>
  <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - <% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].map do |s| %>
    <%= s["airline"] %> <% end %><br> <hr> <% end %>` - This is what I did and it is still not working.

Comment: Please. Something surely is wrong with how I am parsing array of hashes.

Comment: Please make your response example smaller and past hier, than i can help you.