# Rails traverse deep array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this very confusing array of hashes as an API response.

http://jsfiddle.net/PP9N5/

( the full response is massive. Posting only a part of it but it covers all elements of the response)
How can I get to "airlines".

I tried this

```
<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].each do|h| %>
  <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong> - 
  <% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].each do |s| %>
    <%= s['airline'] %>
  <% end %> <br> <hr>
<% end %>
```

And I get this error

> can't convert String into Integer

I did some modifications like

```
<%= h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].first["airline"] %>
Error received - can't convert String into Integer
```

and

```
<%= h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"][0]["airline"] %>
Error received - undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Isnt there a simple way, like I say to find a key "airline" and for that key it returns its value. I stumbled upon [this link](http://qugstart.com/blog/uncategorized/ruby-multi-level-nested-hash-value/), though I dont get any error, I also dont get any result.

Thanks.

UPDATE

I did this

```
<% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].each do |o,p| %>
<% if o=="airline" %> <%= p %> <% end %>
 <% end %> <br> <hr>
<% end %>
```

I can get few values of airlines where inside segment there is no array.
For eg, i can get where departure_date_time is 2014-07-07T07:10:00, index = 5.

http://jsfiddle.net/PP9N5/1/  (scroll down)

Comment: You might look into https://github.com/raganwald/andand

Comment: You can chain the access to the hash's key/value pairs by using `.try`: `h.try(:[], 'flights').try(:[], 'flight').try(:[], 'segments')` etc.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I get the array of `segment` but cant get inside of it. `try(:[], 'airline')` adding this still says `can't convert String into Integer`

Comment: I am sure the way i access the key is not correct. What could be the right approach if i am traversing.

Comment: This means that you are trying to access a value of an Array with the way you access a Hash (with a string/symbol). (try `[]['string']` in your IRB console to see the same error message)

Comment: @MrYoshiji So how can i correct that.

Comment: @Skram Without the gem, how will you suggest to traverse inside such an array/hash.

Comment: What you are showing in the jsfiddle ends with a comma. This does not look like a complete/valid hash.

Comment: @seph Yes it is only a part of the massive response from the API. It has all the elements though. I have put upto 9 values, chk `"index" => '9'` from below. Total has over 200.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails traverse hash from API XML response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570365/rails-traverse-hash-from-api-xml-response)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code you can add which will extract all keys equal the parameter in any `Hash` within your `Hash`:

```
class Hash
  def deep_find(query, &block)
    flat_map do |key, value|
      if key == query
        yield value if block_given?
        [value]
      elsif value.is_a? Hash
        value.deep_find(query, &block)
      elsif value.is_a? Array
        value.select { |i| i.is_a? Hash }.flat_map { |h| h.deep_find(query, &block) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example:

```
hash = {"h" => [{ 'x' => [1, 5] }, { 'x' => 2 }, { 'f' => { 'x' => [3, 4] } }], 'x' => 6 }
hash.deep_find('x') { |x| puts "#{x}" }
# [1, 5]
# 2
# [3, 4]
# 6
# => [[1, 5], 2, [3, 4], 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a tipical problem :D

Replace "=>" for ":" and render.

```
your_json = {.....}
your_json.gsub("=>", ":")
puts your_json
```

You can validate a JSON before to work it with http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Updated with a example

Comment: Thing is the response from the API was an XML. Httparty converted the response to this state.

Comment: You know i now able to get few values where there is no array inside segment. See updated ques.