# Rails display value based on key in deep array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the array of hashes received as parsed_response from an API response which was XML, using Httparty.

Difficult and confusing to traverse inside and get the value.

```
"flights"=>{
    "flight"=>{
        "segments"=>{
            "segment"=>[   (this has square brackets)
                {
                    "index"=>"3",
                    "departure_airport"=>"DEL",
                    "arrival_airport"=>"CCU",
                    "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T13:20:00",
                    "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T15:35:00",
                    "flight_number"=>"20",
                    "airline"=>"AI",
                    "operating_airline"=>"AI",
                    "stops"=>"0",
                    "equipment"=>"320",
                    "duration"=>"8100"
                },
                {
                    "index"=>"4",
                    "departure_airport"=>"CCU",
                    "arrival_airport"=>"BLR",
                    "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T18:10:00",
                    "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T20:40:00",
                    "flight_number"=>"771",
                    "airline"=>"AI",
                    "operating_airline"=>"AI",
                    "stops"=>"0",
                    "equipment"=>"319",
                    "duration"=>"9000"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

To display above hash values I did

```
<% h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"].each do |o,p| %>
      <% if o.class == Hash %> 
          <strong><%= o['airline'] %></strong> 
          <%= o['arrival_airport']  %> - <%= o['arrival_date_time']  %><br>
      <% else %>
          <%= o  %>
      <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

*(**NOTE**: Simply placing* `o['airline']` *after loop would give* `can't convert String into Integer`)

The else statement is to parse the below type of response.

```
"flights"=>{
    "flight"=>{
        "segments"=>{
            "segment"=>{     (no square brackets)
                    "index"=>"3",
                    "departure_airport"=>"DEL",
                    "arrival_airport"=>"CCU",
                    "departure_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T13:20:00",
                    "arrival_date_time"=>"2014-07-07T15:35:00",
                    "flight_number"=>"20",
                    "airline"=>"AI",
                    "operating_airline"=>"AI",
                    "stops"=>"0",
                    "equipment"=>"320",
                    "duration"=>"8100"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

So having <%= o %> after else statment, will give

```
["index", "7"] ["departure_airport", "DEL"] ["arrival_airport", "BLR"] ["departure_date_time", "2014-07-10T07:10:00"] ["arrival_date_time", "2014-07-10T09:50:00"] ["flight_number", "807"] ["airline", "9W"] ["operating_airline", "9W"] ["stops", "0"] ["equipment", "738"] ["duration", "9600"]
```

But having `<% elsif o=="departure_airport" %> <%= p %> <% end %>` in-place of else statement, will give the value associated with the key.

To get a single value using the key, this is fine. But it really gets messy to put all those key in the above format to get their values.

There should be a better way to parse it, but just cant figure out how will I deduce a use case where ['segment'] would give the result appropriately, based on if it is again a  hash or it is just a key.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails traverse deep array of hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579053/rails-traverse-deep-array-of-hashes)

Comment: Certain duplicate, same poster..

Comment: @dax No it is not a possible duplicate. That ques was asked by me. I was just not able to traverse inside. This ques is an update where I have to place some awkward statements. Like to improve on it.

Comment: is my answer working?

Comment: You should revise your current question rather than making new ones.  This is the third time you've asked what is basically the same question, and each one has received good answers.

Comment: @dax and finally i got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here would be to wrap the `Hash` into an `Array` before looping it.

**controller**

```
@segments_array = Array.wrap(h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"])
```

**view**

```
<% @segments_array.each do |segment| %>

  <strong><%= segment['airline'] %></strong> 
  <%= segment['arrival_airport']  %> - <%= segment['arrival_date_time']  %><br>
  ...

<% end %>
```

Comment: This is the result for `<%= segment %>` which is after else statement. `["index", "7"] ["departure_airport", "DEL"] ["arrival_airport", "BLR"] ["departure_date_time", "2014-07-10T07:10:00"] ["arrival_date_time", "2014-07-10T09:50:00"] ["flight_number", "807"] ["airline", "9W"] ["operating_airline", "9W"] ["stops", "0"] ["equipment", "738"] ["duration", "9600"]`

Comment: No change in what I had got initially.

Comment: I wonder if rendering a partial specifying a `:collection` would handle the single item vs. array, eliminating the need for the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found a way to wrap the single `Hash` into an `Array`, so now its even more DRY :)

Comment: I have to say again. That just worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now i am onto improving the code structure. [Pls advise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25060509/2096740)

Answer (score 0):

```
[h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"]].flatten.each do |segment|
  puts "#{segment['arrival_airport']} - #{segment['arrival_date_time']}"
end
```

HTH

Comment: Nope. That does not help. i only get result where after segment it is a square bracket. Hash. The first block of parsed_response above. Not for the second block of parsed_response. It only displays raw key and value.