# Improving API calls and responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

[TheChamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235594/thechamp) helped me out to sort out with the array of hashes issue. Thanks. Now I would like to improve on that. It is really messy in the views

1. Move the code to model, so only calling the instance variable will show the desired result. Like one variable for flight types, the departure times, price structure, etc.
2. Have the result sorted in the model itself, based on some conditions. Like for price, default to lowest first.
3. It takes a lot of time to get the API response. What are the various options to cache the response, so results are instantaneous. Also, what values need to be checked to ensure the cache is fresh.

This is my code base. (for ur consideration, a portion of API response - http://jsfiddle.net/PP9N5/)

Model

```
class Cleartrip
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout

  base_uri "api.staging.cleartrip.com/air/1.0/search"
  headers 'X-CT-API-KEY' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  format :xml

  def self.get_flight

    response = get("?from=DEL&to=BLR&depart-date=2014-08-10&adults=1&children=0&infants=0") 
    if response.success?
      response
    else
      raise response.message
    end


 end
```

Controller

```
# This does nothing
expires_in 20.minutes, public: true 

@flight = Cleartrip.get_flight
```

Views

```
<table>
<tbody>

<% @flight["air_search_result"]["onward_solutions"]["solution"].each do |h| %>


<tr>
  <td> # This gets the flight info
    <% Array.wrap(h["flights"]["flight"]["segments"]["segment"]).each do |segment| %>


          <strong><%= segment['airline'] %></strong> <br>
          <%= segment['departure_airport']  %> - <%= segment['departure_date_time']  %> ||     
          <%= segment['arrival_airport']  %> - <%= segment['arrival_date_time']  %> <br>


    <% end %>
    <hr>
  </td>

  <td> # this gets the type of fare, Refundable/ Non-refundable
    <%= h["pax_pricing_info_list"]["pax_pricing_info"]["pricing_info_list"]["pricing_info"]["fare_type"] %>

  </td>

  <td> # This gets the fare structure
    <% h["pax_pricing_info_list"]["pax_pricing_info"]["pricing_info_list"]["pricing_info"]["pricing_elements"]["pricing_element"].each do |f| %>
    <%= f['category']%> - <%= f['amount'] %> <br>
    <% end %>

  </td>

  <td> # The pricing summary
    <strong><%=h["pricing_summary"]["total_fare"] %></strong>
  </td>

</tr> 

<% end %>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Appreciate general guidelines.

Thanks.

Comment: your `h` variable seems to be solutions? Or flight? How would you describe that variable?

Comment: 'h' is for the first do statement. It traverses the hash inside 'solution'.

Comment: Hello @TheChamp any idea how to implement caching? I did some experiments but none pass - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095140/beginning-api-caching

Comment: @TheChamp knows but its a secret. Sorry arjun