# Beginning API caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone point to me the correct technique wch relates to caching of API responses.

I have been thru lots of existing questions, guides, posts but somewhere some crucial element is not working right.

Model

```
class Cleartrip
  include HTTParty

  debug_output $stdout

  base_uri "api.staging.cleartrip.com/air/1.0/search"
  headers 'X-CT-API-KEY' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  format :xml

  def self.get_flight(url)
    Rails.cache.fetch(url, :expires => 1.hour) do
      response = get(url) 
      if response.success?
        response
      else
        raise response.message
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Controller

```
@flight = Cleartrip.get_flight("?from=DEL&to=BLR&depart-date=2014-08-10&adults=1&children=0&infants=0")
```

Development.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :null_store
```

Instead of `:null_store`, previously I had `:memory` and I received `Type Error: Can't dump IO`.

Even with the current configs, on every reload it hits the server and takes a lot of time to display the result.

What is it that needs to be done? Which technique or gem, for that matter, takes care of caching? There are many flight search sites, like Google.com/flights or Cleartrip.com itself, there rendering of results is almost instantaneous. Do you know of any tips and tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
if response.success?
        response.parsed_response
else
```

Comment: excellent. That did it. I have also one qustion. Chk this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25161779/2096740